# How i add array attrribute in class diagram UML

Tags: uml

am using uml to implement my class diagram. 
I have a class diagram named `user` . I want to add user preferences as an array of string without using table.

I would ask if i can use an array of string as an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem. Simply append the array dimension as shown below:

[image]

Defaults can be specified following the equal sign.

Comment: it means that StringArray can  contains  those values:[null, "string1","string2",...] ?